# How can i pass a variable with multiple outputs to a Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Here is what I have. I'm looking to ping a range of IP addresses. My code works in the sense that I can put in my variables, octet 3 and 4 for both start and end and get the result I want in the console. All addresses come up in the range and tell me whether they pass or fail. My issue is i'm trying to pass each address to the same JLabel in a multi-line sense like shown in console.  With this code, I only get the last address output in the JLabel. What am I missing?  Again, I get the result I want in Console, just need to get the same result in JLabel. An example:

Console shows
10.91.50.1
10.91.50.2
10.91.50.3
10.91.50.4

JLabel **only returns** : 10.91.50.4

**See code below**:

```
btnCheckPing1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //System.out.println("Check Ping Range");
            /*
                start ip 10.0.a.b       end ip 10.0.x.y
            */
            a = lowX.getText();  // 3rd octet, first group
            b = lowY.getText();  // 4th octet, first group
            x = highX.getText(); // 3rd octet, second group
            y = highY.getText(); // 4th octet, second group
            String pingThis = "";

            int convertA = Integer.parseInt(a);
            int convertB = Integer.parseInt(b);
            int convertX = Integer.parseInt(x);
            int convertY = Integer.parseInt(y);

            if(convertA == convertX) {
                System.out.println("3rd Octet is in range");
                // can ping range


                for(int i = convertB; i <= convertY; i++) {
                    //System.out.println("10.92." + x + "." + i);
                    pingThis = "10.92." + x + "." + i;/
                    //System.out.println(pingThis);
                    try {
                    InetAddress pingRange = InetAddress.getByName(pingThis);
                    boolean reachableGroup = pingRange.isReachable(100);

                    if(reachableGroup == true) {
                        //System.out.println(pingRange + " is valid");
                   /////////Output to JLabel will go here./////////////
                        lblRangeOut.setText(pingThis);

                    } else {
                        //System.out.println(pingRange + " is not valid");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Nothing goes here
                }}
            } else {
                // cannot ping range
                System.out.println("3rd octet out of range");
            }

            //System.out.println("10.92." + a + "." + b + " " + "10.92." + x + "." + y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use a JLabel. Instead use a JTextArea so you can append multiple lines of text. You can make the text are non-editable and transparent so it looks more like a Jlabel.

Answer (score -1):

you are using setter, which is overriding previous value. What you need to do then, is to append your output at the end of the previous one like:

```
lblRangeOut.setText(lblRangeOut.getText() + pingThis)
```

Also as camickr mentioned in a comment, JLabel would not be my first choice in the first place :) Appearantly, as he also pointed out. JLabel does not accept any line separators. for those reasons the JTextArea would be much better and the code would look something like:

```
txtRangeOut.setText(txtRangeOut.getText() + System.lineSeparator() + pingThis)
```

Either way, the main reason for replacing previous value was that setter overrides it. So the new value needs to consist of both previous value and the appended string.

Comment: Awesome. The combination helped here.  I didn't think JLabel was the right choice either but only a month into this teaching myself. I thought TextArea was better but I didn't like that the end user could edit it. SetEditable corrected that to.

Comment: (1-) a JLabel doesn't recognize a line separator. Text is always displayed on the same line unless you use HTML.